# Can anyone tell me where these users and groups came from? (sshd, devtoolsuser, aspnet & netmon users, ssh users, performance log users)

Tags: windows-10, permissions, user-accounts, user-groups

I ran into an issue with "an administrator has blocked you from running xx app" which shouldnt be happening due to the fact im obviously administrator on my pc, and i have real-time/smartscreen disabled.  Might be par for the course under the specific circumstance, but i'd never seen it before so i began digging.

netplwiz has a solid half a dozen "groups" assigned to my account whereas my other pc's have just administrators group.   I decided that in case this was a contributing factor, to clean up.

additional groups assigned - I have netmon users (which i assume is from network performance monitor 3.4) performance log users (i have no idea) and ssh users (also no idea).

userwise I have
[image]

I think ASPNET came from accidentally enabling ASP.NET 4.8 in windows features?

DevToolsUser i have no idea

sshd I also have no idea

would love to get rid of them, which is obviously easy enough with a delete button.  I dont want to do so without understanding their origin however - as i imagine adding them back will be twice as difficult if needed without knowing that.

I do use git and have visual studio installed etc, so i want to be sure its not something added by anything like that and needed.

Comment: devtoolsuser is part of developer mode: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development  The rest are likely related to whatever dev tools/environment you've set up.

Comment: hmm doesnt seem that simple.  I assumed developer mode as well as far as devtoolsuser, yet my other pc has exactly the same (just double checked) settings under For developers, and the user doesnt even exist.

im with ya on some of the "likely" relations but cant take the risk just in case.

someone will know for certain.   In other news - i wish uninstalls did a bettter job cleaning up after themselves.

Comment: You could look in Event Viewer to see when the accounts in question were created, ID 4720. Compare that do your various software installs.

Answer (score 1):

ASP is from when you’ve checked a box adding additional  programs and functions, same with the dev user, you’ve at some point in settings opted for developer rights. You can disable the accounts, I too hate extra clutter but just be sure by disabling you’re not then effecting any policies you may have set I.e an extra account needs to be activated for RDP connections.

Comment: Hmm, worth noting that ASPNET was auto disabled when i found it.  sshd and devtoolsuser were not.

I deleted ASPNET to test, and re enabled the programs & features option for it.   It was not re-added which concerns me.

I wonder if these guys are tied to visual studio somehow.  Im gonna roll back an image for now, as you noted disabling may be the only "surefire" safe way to have them half out of the way, for now until i know EXACTLY how to put them back/where theyre from.

Answer (score 0):

Quite often these programs have dependencies or package providers,etc that are automatically installed when given the option, in the process configuration changed are implemented.